opening vue 3 inside bootstrap modal - SyntaxError: Identifier 'createApp' has already been declared
when page1 with vue loads page2 with vue in a bootstrap modal it errors out with:
SyntaxError: Identifier 'createApp' has already been declared
page1.html:
<script>
    const {
        createApp,
        ref
    } = Vue
    createApp({
        setup() {
            const user_id = ref();
            return {
                user_id
            }
        }
    }).mount('#app_page1');
</script>

page2.html:
<script>
    const {
        createApp,
        ref
    } = Vue
    createApp({
        setup() {
            const files = ref();
            return {
                files
            }
        }
    }).mount('#app_page2');
</script>


As you are fetching the createApp twice in the same DOM thus having this issue, you can simply define the createApp once const {createApp, ref} = Vue in a global file and then use it.

"when page1 with vue loads page2"- please, clarify how this is done

const inside <script> creates global variables that cannot be redeclared.
A way to avoid this is to use scoped variables in all embedded scripts, e.g. with a block:
<script>
{
    const {
        createApp,
        ref
    } = Vue
    ...
}
</script>

For an unbundled app that uses Vue CDN a less quirky way is to use native modules, this won't require to use blocks due to how variable scopes work in ES modules, e.g. for embedded scripts:
<script type="module">
const {
    createApp,
    ref
} = Vue
...

